# Can I get to a post in the iOS app with its URL or ID?

Tags: feature-request, support, ios-app

I was looking at an SE site on which I have an account in my mobile browser, and I found an answer I wanted to upvote. I wasn't logged in, though. Ugh; that's two or three other pages to load, and my password is a pain to type out on this keyboard. The iOS app has me logged in already, though, so maybe I could just grab the link?

Is there any way to do that? Can I launch the iOS app, armed with either a URL or a site name and post ID, and get directly to that post?

If not, please consider this a feature request.

Comment: As an inconvenient-but-not-impossible solution you could jump to the site in the site list and then abuse `inquestion:<id>` in the search field, but that sounds like a lot of tricky typing and text selection. A direct route would be great.

Comment: That's a handy tip, @TimStone, thanks! I didn't know about that search option.

Comment: /me slaps forehead @ShadowWizard. How did I miss that one?!

Comment: lol no worry @Josh, this happens to me too when I'm sure nobody thought of that marvellous feature request/bug report before. ;)